# FindMinimum::lstol

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

I have a function `SQ[b,zQ,zh]` where I want to find at which `zQ` it is a minimum given `b` and `zh`. I set `b=10^-x` and `zh=1.355 10^-x` where I choose `x`. For `x=3` I encounter a `FindMinimum::lstol` issue. I have tried changing `MaxRecursion` and `WorkingPrecision` but it is not resolved. Can anyone help me with this?

I also want to extend the calculation for larger `x=4,5,...,10`

```
d = 3;
ag = 10;
pg = 10;
wp = 50;
f[z_, zh_] := 1 - (z/zh)^(d + 1);
torootsig[b_?NumericQ, sig_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{br, sigr, zQr, zhr}, {br, sigr, zQr, zhr} = Rationalize[{b, sig, zQ, zh}, 0]; br - NIntegrate[z^d/Sqrt[f[z, zhr] (zQr^(2 d) (1 + (sigr^2/f[zQr, zhr])) - z^(2 d))], {z, 0, zQr}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxRecursion -> 100]]
sig[b_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := sig /. FindRoot[torootsig[b, sig, zQ, zh] == 0, {sig, -50 1.3 10^-3, 0}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxIterations -> 100]
intSQ1[b_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{br, zQr, zhr}, {br, zQr, zhr} = Rationalize[{b, zQ, zh}, 0]; (-1/(d - 1)) (1/(zQr^(2 d) (1 + sig[br, zQr, zhr]^2/f[zQr, zhr]))) NIntegrate[z^d Sqrt[f[z, zhr]/(1 - (1/(zQr^(2 d) (1 + sig[br, zQr, zhr]^2/f[zQr, zhr]))) z^(2 d))], {z, 0, zQr}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxRecursion -> 100]]
intSQ2[b_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{br, zQr, zhr}, {br, zQr, zhr} = Rationalize[{b, zQ, zh}, 0]; (-1/(2 zhr^(d + 1))) ((d + 1)/(d - 1)) NIntegrate[z Sqrt[(1 - (1/(zQr^(2 d) (1 + sig[br, zQr, zhr]^2/f[zQr, zhr]))) z^(2 d))/f[z, zhr]], {z, 0, zQr}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxRecursion -> 100]]
intSQ3[b_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{br, zQr, zhr}, {br, zQr, zhr} = Rationalize[{b, zQ, zh}, 0]; (1/zhr)^(d + 1) NIntegrate[z/Sqrt[f[z, zhr] (1 - (1/(zQr^(2 d) (1 + sig[br, zQr, zhr]^2/f[zQr, zhr]))) z^(2 d))], {z, 0, zQr}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxRecursion -> 300, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]]
SQ[b_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{br, zQr, zhr}, {br, zQr, zhr} = Rationalize[{b, zQ, zh}, 0]; (-Sqrt[f[zQr, zhr] (1 - (1/(zQr^(2 d) (1 + sig[br, zQr, zhr]^2/f[zQr, zhr]))) zQr^(2 d))]/((d - 1) zQr^(d - 1)) + intSQ1[br, zQr, zhr] + intSQ2[br, zQr, zhr] + intSQ3[br, zQr, zhr] + 1/zQr^(d - 1))/4 ]

x = 3;
FindMinimum[{SQ[10^-x, zQ, 1.355 10^-x]/10^(2 x)}, {zQ, 0.9955 1.355 10^-x, 0.995 1.355 10^-x, 0.996 1.355 10^-x}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxIterations -> 500] // AbsoluteTiming
FindMinimum::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within the tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the function. You may need more than 50.` digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.
{598.3201164, {0.19195144250523353513414807356587315266329459419565, {zQ -> 0.0013490146179865683928983415239627338448699548869898}}}
```

There is definitely a minimum as is shown below,

```
x = 3;
Plot[SQ[10^-x, n 1.355 10^-x, 1.355 10^-x]/10^(2 x), {n, 0.995, 0.996}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.005]}, PlotRange -> Full, ImageSize -> Large] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Comment: Your functions are numerical therefore the optimal solution can be computed with `NMinimize`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I have tried `NMinimize` with the same range given above (excluding initial point) and it just keeps running for so long and not ending so I just aborted it around 30 minutes later. That's so exaggerated for only one point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can simplifier this code to avoid recursive usage of some functions during evaluation as follows

```
d = 3;
pg = 10;
f[z_, zh_] := 1 - (z/zh)^(d + 1);
torootsig[b_?NumericQ, sig_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := 
  Module[{br = b, sigr = sig, zQr = zQ, zhr = zh}, 
   i1 = br - 
     NIntegrate[
      z^d/Sqrt[
        f[z, zhr] (zQr^(2 d) (1 + (sigr^2/f[zQr, zhr])) - 
           z^(2 d))], {z, 0, zQr}, PrecisionGoal -> pg]; i1];
sig[b_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := 
  sig /. FindRoot[
    torootsig[b, sig, zQ, zh] == 0, {sig, -50 1.3 10^-3, 0}];
intSQ1[b_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := 
  Module[{br = b, zQr = zQ, zhr = zh}, 
   i2 = (-1/(d - 
         1)) (1/(zQr^(2 d) (1 + 
           sig[br, zQr, zhr]^2/f[zQr, zhr]))) NIntegrate[
      z^d Sqrt[
        f[z, zhr]/(1 - (1/(zQr^(2 d) (1 + 
                  sig[br, zQr, zhr]^2/f[zQr, zhr]))) z^(2 d))], {z, 0,
        zQr}, PrecisionGoal -> pg]; i2];
intSQ2[b_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := 
  Module[{br = b, zQr = zQ, zhr = zh}, 
   i3 = (-1/(2 zhr^(d + 1))) ((d + 1)/(d - 1)) NIntegrate[
      z Sqrt[(1 - (1/(zQr^(2 d) (1 + 
                  sig[br, zQr, zhr]^2/f[zQr, zhr]))) z^(2 d))/
         f[z, zhr]], {z, 0, zQr}, PrecisionGoal -> pg]];
intSQ3[b_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{br = b, zQr = zQ, zhr = zh}, 
  i4 = (1/zhr)^(d + 1) NIntegrate[
     z/Sqrt[f[z, 
         zhr] (1 - (1/(zQr^(2 d) (1 + 
                 sig[br, zQr, zhr]^2/f[zQr, zhr]))) z^(2 d))], {z, 0, 
      zQr}, PrecisionGoal -> pg, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]; i4]
SQ[b_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := 
  Module[{br = b, zQr = zQ, zhr = zh}, 
   i5 = (-Sqrt[
          f[zQr, zhr] (1 - (1/(zQr^(2 d) (1 + 
                    sig[br, zQr, zhr]^2/
                    f[zQr, zhr]))) zQr^(2 d))]/((d - 1) zQr^(d - 1)) +
        intSQ1[br, zQr, zhr] + intSQ2[br, zQr, zhr] + 
       intSQ3[br, zQr, zhr] + 1/zQr^(d - 1))/4; i5];
```

With this code we can compute list and use `Interpolation` to plot `SQ`

```
x = 3;
lst = Table[{n, 
    10^(-2 x) SQ[10^-x, n 1.355 10^-x, 1.355 10^-x] // Quiet // 
     Chop}, {n, 0.995, 0.996, .0001}];

f0 = Interpolation[lst];

Plot[f0[n], {n, 0.995, 0.996}]
```

[image: Figure1]
Finally we compute min value

```
FindMinimum[f0[n], {n, .9956}]

Out[]= {0.191951, {n -> 0.995583}}
```

Comment: You used `Table` to estimate the values near the minimum and used `Interpolation` to get an estimated curve. From there, you used the interpolated curve to find the minimum. Nice approach, seems accurate.

Answer (score 4):

Without defining any precision and accuracy goals and also without pre-setting any working precision we have:

```
d=3;
f[z_,zh_]:=1-(z/zh)^(d+1);
torootsig[b_?NumericQ,sig_?NumericQ,zQ_?NumericQ,zh_?NumericQ]:=b-NIntegrate[z^d/Sqrt[f[z,zh] (zQ^(2 d) (1+(sig^2/f[zQ,zh]))-z^(2 d))],{z,0,zQ}]
sig[b_?NumericQ,zQ_?NumericQ,zh_?NumericQ]:=sig/.FindRoot[torootsig[b,sig,zQ,zh]==0,{sig,-50 1.3 10^-3,0}]
intSQ1[b_?NumericQ,zQ_?NumericQ,zh_?NumericQ]:=(-1/(d-1)) (1/(zQ^(2 d) (1+sig[b,zQ,zh]^2/f[zQ,zh]))) NIntegrate[z^d Sqrt[f[z,zh]/(1-(1/(zQ^(2 d) (1+sig[b,zQ,zh]^2/f[zQ,zh]))) z^(2 d))],{z,0,zQ},MaxRecursion->100]
intSQ2[b_?NumericQ,zQ_?NumericQ,zh_?NumericQ]:=(-1/(2 zh^(d+1))) ((d+1)/(d-1)) NIntegrate[z Sqrt[(1-(1/(zQ^(2 d) (1+sig[b,zQ,zh]^2/f[zQ,zh]))) z^(2 d))/f[z,zh]],{z,0,zQ},MaxRecursion->100]
intSQ3[b_?NumericQ,zQ_?NumericQ,zh_?NumericQ]:=(1/zh)^(d+1) NIntegrate[z/Sqrt[f[z,zh] (1-(1/(zQ^(2 d) (1+sig[b,zQ,zh]^2/f[zQ,zh]))) z^(2 d))],{z,0,zQ},MaxRecursion->300]
SQ[b_?NumericQ,zQ_?NumericQ,zh_?NumericQ]:=(-Sqrt[f[zQ,zh] (1-(1/(zQ^(2 d) (1+sig[b,zQ,zh]^2/f[zQ,zh]))) zQ^(2 d))]/((d-1) zQ^(d-1))+intSQ1[b,zQ,zh]+intSQ2[b,zQ,zh]+intSQ3[b,zQ,zh]+1/zQ^(d-1))/4
```

Then we can estimate the minimum for $x=3,4,\ldots,10$ (with a lot of warnings):

```
 Table[{x,FindMinimum[{SQ[10^-x, zQ, 1.355 10^-x]/10^(2 x)}, {zQ, 0.9955 1.355 10^-x, 0.995 1.355 10^-x, 0.996 1.355 10^-x}]}, {x,Range[3, 10]}]

{{3, {0.191951, {zQ -> 0.00134901}}},{4, {0.191951, {zQ -> 0.000134897}}}, {5, {0.191952, {zQ -> 0.000013489}}}, {6, {0.191952, {zQ -> 1.3489*10^-6}}}, {7, {0.191952, {zQ -> 1.3489*10^-7}}}, {8, {0.191952, {zQ ->1.3489*10^-8}}}, {9, {0.191952, {zQ -> 1.3489*10^-9}}}, {10, {0.191952, {zQ -> 1.3489*10^-10}}}}
```

I have checked graphically for x=3 and x=4 and the minimum values seem to make sense.